# MySQL server is not run

Tags: mysql

MySQL server is not run.
I installed MySQL server from https://dev.mysql.com ,instance is stranded like image.
[image]

When I run command from terminal like

```
mysql.server start
```

Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.pid). error happens.
When I searched this error solution, so I run command

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
```

and `sudo mysql.server start`, so same error happens.
So I tried another error solution,
I run command `cd /usr/local/var/mysql/` & `mysql.server start` ,
Starting MySQL
.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe: line 198: /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.err: Permission denied
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.pid).
```

error happens.
When I run command `mysql.server status` ,ERROR! MySQL is not running error happens.And when I run `mysql.server stop;` ,ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found! error happens.I think MySQL is  moved from the image but it is not true.How can I move it?
And I want to search Database name , so how should I do?

Comment: try removing /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.pid and then start

Comment: /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.pid  file is not exsisted ,so I cannot remove it

Answer (score 1):

It seems clearly permission issue, make sure to provide full permission to below path, as you could see in error.

`usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.err: Permission denied`
`/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/` etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I run command,

Comment: `sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/mysqld_safe
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.err
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/` 
but when I run sudo mysql.server start, ... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.pid). error happens

Comment: How should I fix this?

Comment: Provide full permission to `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/**` recursively either using command or GUI, you could refer [link](http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-the-terminal/) or do some google, you should get it.

Comment: I added full permission to  `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/bin/**`  ,but 
Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.pid).  error happens.How should I fix this?

Comment: Does it work now, or same problem?

Comment: I think it is same problem.
When I run mysqld_safe,
2018-06-12T05:51:35.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.err'.
2018-06-12T05:51:36.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2018-06-12T05:51:36.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/xxxxoMacBook.pid ended     is shown.

Comment: But your logs this time appears like it worked. You may reboot the machine, it should connect I believe.

Comment: thank you,I could work MySQL!!thank you very much.By the way, do you know how I can search DataBase name?

Comment: Great that it helped you! Could you accept this as a correct answer and upvote it.